# настройка nginx с использованием lua

Tags: nginx, lua

Хочется настраивать конфиг nginx на лету успользуя lua.
Пытался настроить listen через переменную $port. Не получилось. Как я понял listen и server_name нельзя указать через переменную. 
Есть способ,даже в теории,  для указания listen через переменную?

Comment: Нет. Даже в теории нет. Вернее в теории вы можете написать свой nginx, но боюсь никто не оценит

Comment: можно так составить конфиг, чтобы апстрим вычислялся в зависимости от $port